# Flutter: Nothing happens in the Debug-Mode

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to copy the code from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmkwOygpaqg&t=588s

I stopped at 18:15 and tried to debug the code.
But after the loading I got a whitescreen and the code stopped in the main-method every time at `await`.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I tried to run `flutter channel stable` and `flutter upgrade`. But it does not help me in this case.
It seems like I took a breaking point or the code is waiting for something.

Did I forget something in my settings or what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a breakpoint set on the await line in main? (usually a red circle to the left of the line number) If you did, you should just need to click a continue button once the code is stopped at that line. You can either press the continue button, click on the break point to remove it, or start without debugging

Comment: No. I dont have a breaking point on the line. There I said that it seems. 
After I tried to run the code I get this Error:
A Dart VM Service on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:54343/NBzXdP-ZmPU=
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:54343/NBzXdP-ZmPU=
TypeError: Class constructor IndexedDBLocalPersistence cannot be invoked without 'new'. But I dont know how to fix it...